# A non-Finsler metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, finsler-geometry

I am looking for a *inner* metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (that induces the *standard topology*) which is not Finsler.

By "Finsler" here I mean a metric that is obtained by the following construction:

1. pick a smooth structure on $\mathbb R^2$ and take a suitable continuous function $\mu$ on $T\mathbb R^2$
2. define a metric as $d(x,y):=\inf_\gamma \int \mu(\dot\gamma) dt $ over all piecewise smooth paths $\gamma$ connecting two points $x,y$.

If exists, it is necessarily non-invariant (Berestovski theorem).

Comment: What about the geodesic metric on the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$, $z\ge 0$ (which is homeomorphic to the plane?) Or similarly, the quotient of $\mathbf{R}^2$ by $x\mapsto -x$, with distance induced by $\min(d(x,y),d(x,-y))$.

Comment: The real question (originally due to Busemann) is "what is the characterization of Finsler distance functions among path-metrics on surfaces?" See "Foundations of singular Finsler geometry" by P.Andreev for some recent progress in this direction.

Comment: @MoisheKohan it's somewhat open-ended. Characterization in which terms?

Comment: @YCor: Similar to Nikolaev's theorem characterizing Riemannian metrics among  path metrics. The first condition would be local extendibility of geodesics, which fails in both examples that you gave. Compare my answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375758/is-a-differentiable-manifold-with-a-metric-a-finsler-space/2375995#2375995) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106508/existence-of-a-riemannian-metric-inducing-a-given-distance/673742#673742).

Comment: See also 2nd answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93798/alexandrov-geometry-techniques-for-finsler-manifolds?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Will you be interested in a 3-dimensional example?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin very much interested! in this case i would like to have something  which is not sub-Finsler too, and not of a cone-type singularity type suggested by YCor in the first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your metric has to be geodesic, in particular
$$d(x,y)=\min \{\,1,|x-y|\,\}$$
is not Finsler in your sense.

Now let $d$ be a geodesic metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose $n=2$.
In ["Two counterexamples..." by Burago, Ivanov, and Shoenthal](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=aa&paperid=102&option_lang=eng), it was conjectured that a neighborhood of any point in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ admits a Lipschitz embedding into the Euclidean plane.

Suppose $d$ is a Finsler metric in your sense.
Since $\mu$ is continuous, the natural map $(\mathbb{R}^n,d)\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a locally lipschitz homeomorphism.
So this conjecture is closely related to your question.

Now suppose $n=3$.
The same paper provides an example of a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that (locally) does not admit a Lipschitz embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$.
In particular, $d$ is not a Finsler metric in your sense.
(The construction is interesting --- it is worth reading.)